# Deleting specific files in command line

Tags: command-line

I have files **fileName_1**, **fileName_2** ... **fileName_100000** where the fileNames are numbered sequentially. How can I delete the files of index greater than, say **100**?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If filenames are numbered sequentially just run the following command:

```
rm fileName_{100..100000}
```

Comment: Info: This works because bash (your shell) will expand the `{x..y}` to the whole list. For example if you use `echo test{1..3}` it will be expanded to `echo test1 test2 test3` and then executed. As you can see, it prints `test1 test2 test3`. Similarly, if the `{x..y}` is not connected to any argument, it will just put the numbers there. E.g. `echo test {1..3}` will just print `test 1 2 3`.

Comment: Note: there is a limit imposed by the `exec` call to the number of arguments that a process can have. You can retrieve it with `getconf ARG_MAX`. For example on my system it is `2097152` (~2.1 millions). This means that `rm` (which is not a built-in) will fail with more than that many files. Built-in commands don't have this problem, and neither do the other solutions proposed.

Comment: Note that ARG_MAX is a number of bytes, not a number of arguments.  rm can't handle deleting 2097152 files at once.  It could delete 2048 files which each had a name that was 1023 bytes long (not 1024; the delimiters between arguments (\0 in C-land) count towards the limit).

Answer (score 6):

You may try this command also,

```
for i in $(seq 100 100000); do rm fileName_$i; done
```

It will delete all the files(ranges from 100 to 100000) if the filename contains numbers in an sequential order.

Answer (score 5):

In general you have several ways to achieve this:

```
rm fileName_{100..100000}
```

will be expanded by the shell into roughly 100,000 filenames. If the basename is a long path and the number is high enough, you might actually exceed the maximum length of a command line with this approach.

The `for` loop

```
for i in $(seq 100 100000); do rm fileName_$i; done
```

does not suffer from this problem, but is a relatively slow way of deleting the files, as the shell has to perform the variable substitution and launching rm about 100,000 times.

Both methods above might cause warnings if some of the files, say `filename_101` were missing.

Usually, solutions based on `find` are better, as they only work on files that are actually there (during discovery). However, there are some subtle differences:

```
find . -name 'fileName_[100-100000]' -exec rm {} \;
```

will still launch the `rm` program about 100,000 times, while replacing the final `\;` by `+` will try to minimize the number of subprocesses. Both methods will probably be (much or a bit) slower than using `-delete` which does not use external commands at all but invokes system calls instead.

However, *always* check first if the pattern actually matches the files that you want to target:

```
stefan@tuxedo ~ % mkdir askubuntu
stefan@tuxedo ~ % touch askubuntu/filename_{1..1000}
stefan@tuxedo ~ % find askubuntu -name 'filename_[100-1000]' 
askubuntu/filename_1
```

So in this case you'd delete a file you wanted to keep and left the files that should have been removed.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following command:

```
find . -name 'fileName_[100-100000]' -exec rm {} \;
```

That will delete files from 100 to 100000 .

More information: [Site](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm)

Comment: You'd be better off using `+` rather than `\;` -- see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files). Or, even better, use find's `-delete` command.

Comment: I tested this, and it only deleted fileName_1. The `[100-100000]` [character class](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Shell-Pattern-Matching.html) only matches a single character, so it can only match 0 or 1.